# Why is there only default program group in LogicalProgramGroup in WMI?

Tags: visual-c++, window, wmi

When I use the LogicalProgramGroup class in WMI to get groupname, name, and username in the program group, I can only get groupname, name, and username whose username is default. Cannot get other users, such as public. The root permission is also invalid. So how do I get program group information for all user roles？

Comment: The output information in my program contains Chinese characters, so I solved my problem when I used setlocale (LC_ALL, "") in <locale.h>.